# Observer subscribing to ConnectableObservable didn't get notified after connect method

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

Console print nothing after excuting these code

```
ConnectableObservable o = ConnectableObservable.create(emitter -> {
        emitter.onNext("first");
        Thread.sleep(6000);
        emitter.onNext("second");
    }).publish();
    o.connect();
    o.subscribe(
            msg -> Log.i(TAG, "" + msg),
            throwable -> Log.e(TAG, "", (Throwable) throwable)
    );
```

But [the doc](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/connect.html) said

> You can also use the connect method to instruct an Observable to begin emitting items (or, to begin generating items that would be emitted) **even before any Subscriber has subscribed to it.**

Comment: You have a synchronous source that sleeps when `connect` gets called so you will miss both of its items when using `publish`. Consider using `replay()`.

Comment: you' re right, thank you